# How do you convert and append sequence numbers of same named elements to attributes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toplevel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <address>
        <line>address line a</line>
        <line>address line b</line>
        <line>address line c</line>
        <line>address line d</line>
    </address>
</toplevel>
```

as described here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="toplevel">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="4" ref="line"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="line" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and i would like to convert it to this format using SAXON-HE 10.6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toplevel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <address line1="address line a" line2="address line b" line3="address line c" line4="address line d"/>
</toplevel>
```

This is what i have for the transform XLT file but it only works if the lines in the source xml are numbered which unfortunately they aren't. I have tried adding a xsl:for-each and a variable but i can't determine how to append a sequential number to the line attributes. Please note the max number of lines will always be 4 so perhaps it could be hard-coded, but i don't know the syntax. The conversion can easily be done in a programming language but I would really like to know the answer to this using a SAXON-HE 10.6 transform.

thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="."/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="* | text() | @*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="toplevel" mode="copy">  
        <xsl:copy>            
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="address"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="address" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="convert-to-attr" select="*"/>            
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="convert-to-attr">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's easily done as the answer from @ConalTuohy demonstrates, but I do wonder whether its a good idea. As a general rule, names should have no internal structure and no hidden semantics.

Comment: I'd just assumed that this re-encoding was an external requirement i.e. for interoperability with some other system that expects these numbered address line attributes. But if that's not the case, and the author has freely chosen to re-encode the data in this way, then I agree it's a poor choice.

Comment: yes, the fields in the target DMSII structure are specifically labeled. thankyou.

CUST1-ADDRESS-1      ALPHA   ( 035)   INITIALVALUE BLANKS;    
CUST1-ADDRESS-2      ALPHA   ( 035)   INITIALVALUE BLANKS;    
CUST1-ADDRESS-3      ALPHA   ( 035)   INITIALVALUE BLANKS;    
CUST1-ADDRESS-4      ALPHA   ( 035)   INITIALVALUE BLANKS;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Saxon 10 you should probably use XSLT 3.0 rather than 2.0. That lets you use an `xsl:mode` element to copy elements, rather than write your own identity templates.

Here I've used the `position()` function to produce the numbering of the `line` attribute names. This function returns the index (starting from 1) of the context item in the current sequence. In the `for-each`, the `select` attribute selects the 4 `line` child elements, the value of `position()` will take the values `1` to `4` in each iteration of the `for-each`'s sequence constructor (i.e. the `xsl:attribute` statement):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="address">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="line">
          <xsl:attribute name="line{position()}" select="text()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```xml
<toplevel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <address line1="address line a" line2="address line b" line3="address line c" line4="address line d"/>
</toplevel>
```